# Building a contact form in Umbraco 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I'm trying to build a contact form in umbraco v6 by following the following [this](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/forms) tutorial. The problems I'm having are that a) The form seems to be posting on load ie. I'm presented with required field errors on the form by default and b) when I actually populate the data and submit, I get a 404 not found error with the following location: Requested URL: /umbraco/RenderMvc

Here is the code I have for my **Model**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CustomControls
{
    public class ContactFormModel
    {
        [Required, Display(Name = "First name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Surname")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Company")]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Email address")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]        
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Required, Display(Name = "Telephone")]
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my **SurfaceController** code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace CustomControls
{
    public class ContactFormSurfaceController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("ContactForm")]
        public ActionResult ContactFormGet(ContactFormModel model)
        {
            return PartialView("ContactForm", new ContactFormModel());            
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("ContactForm")]
        public ActionResult ContactFormPost(ContactFormModel model)
        {    
            //model not valid, do not save, but return current umbraco page
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Perhaps you might want to add a custom message to the ViewBag
                //which will be available on the View when it renders (since we're not 
                //redirecting)     
                TempData.Add("Status", "Invalid form data");
                //return CurrentUmbracoPage();
                return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
            }
            //if validation passes perform whatever logic
            //In this sample we keep it empty, but try setting a breakpoint to see what is posted here
            //Perhaps you might want to store some data in TempData which will be available 
            //in the View after the redirect below. An example might be to show a custom 'submit
            //successful' message on the View, for example:
            TempData.Add("Status", "Your form was successfully submitted at " + DateTime.Now);
            //redirect to current page to clear the form
            return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();

            //Or redirect to specific page
            //return RedirectToUmbracoPage(1063);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is my **view**:

```
@model CustomControls.ContactFormModel

@using(Html.BeginUmbracoForm("SubmitContactForm", "ContactFormSurface"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model)
    <input type="submit"/>
}

<p class="field-validation-error">@TempData["Status"]</p>
```

This is the snippet of code I'm using in my template to render the form:

```
@Html.Action("ContactForm","ContactFormSurface")
```

Is anyone able to point out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, instead of rendering as a child action:

`@Html.Action("ContactForm","ContactFormSurface")`

you should render the view as a partial view:

`@Html.Partial("ContactFormSurface/ContactForm")`

... pointing to where the view is located.

Comment: Hi Digby, that didn't work unfortunately! I get the error: "The partial view 'ContactFormSurface/ContactForm' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations". Nothing changes even if I move the view into the Views/partials folder

Comment: Sure, the "ContactFormSurface/ContactForm" address has to point to wherever the view is. I don't know where your view is :)

Answer (score 1):

Aha, I found the problem. In my view I'm using the line:

```
@using(Html.BeginUmbracoForm("SubmitContactForm", "ContactFormSurface"))
```

Yet "SubmitContactForm" doesn't exist - I forgot to update the name when I updated the names of my methods :-)

Comment: I read your Answer and I was like "Duh, of course they have to match" and then proceeded to look at mine and realized they didn't match...

Thanks for your "fix"  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move the partials to ~/Views/Shared folder?

As for the partial rendering in a view, this worked for me.

```
@Html.Action(actionName: "ContactForm", controllerName: "ContactFormSurface")
```